# Ruby - How to get rid of escape character and "\n" while converting string to hash value?

Tags: ruby, string

In Ruby, i'm trying to convert a string to a hash value. It shows up with escapse character and "\n" in the string.

Eg:

```
hashex = { keyex: 'example "test" line 1
  line 2 "test2"'}
puts hashex
```

It is printing the result as

```
{:keyex=>"example \"test\" line 1\n  line 2 \"test2\""}
```

I need to get the result as

```
{ keyex: 'example "test" line 1
      line 2 "test2"'}
```

preserving the newline (not '\n') and the "". Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

## Note

```
{:keyex=>"example \"test\" line 1\n  line 2 \"test2\""}
```

is just the way Ruby represents the hash. It is 100% the same object as :

```
{ keyex: 'example "test" line 1
  line 2 "test2"'}
```

even though it might look different.

## Code

You could replace `"\\n"` from `inspect` with newlines, `\"` with `"` and `"` with `'` :

```
hashex = { keyex: 'example "test" line 1
     line 2 "test2"'}

puts hashex.inspect.gsub("\\n", "\n").gsub('"', "'").gsub("\\'",'"')
# {:keyex=>'example "test" line 1
#      line 2 "test2"'}
```

Comment: No way to get rid of that '\'? :(